# Mongo query to sort results with maximum number of distinct attributes or keys?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to write a MongoDB find query to fetch results from a collection and sort them on the basis of maximum attributes per row.

for example:
**right now results are something like this:**

```
[{
    column1 : "abc",
    column2 : "def",
},
{
    column1 : "abc",
},
{
    column1 : "abc",
    column2 : "def",
    column3 : "ghi"
}]
```

**what query should return (in descending order of number of columns):**

```
[{
    column1 : "abc",
    column2 : "def",
    column3 : "ghi"
},
{
    column1 : "abc",
    column2 : "def",
},
{
    column1 : "abc",
}]
```

> Query is db..find({"column1": "abc"});

Is it possible to achieve through querying database?

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: @AndriySimonov It's a simple find query db.<collectionName>.find({"SOME_ATTRIBUTE": "SOME_VALUE" }); returning multiple result as mentioned in the question.

Comment: you can write code that sorts the results yourself, is the number of results too big for that?

Comment: @marmor Yes, the data set is too big.

Comment: @Tairman Do you know all possible fields that can be present in the documents?

Comment: @AndriySimonov No, actually it's a metadata for a document repository and can contain indefinite number of attributes per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not optimal, but you could call mapReduce to get ids by number of fields, and then query for those ids in ascending order, here's some code to start with (**not tested!**)

```
var map = function(doc) {
   emit(Object.keys(doc).length, doc._id);
}
var reduce = function(key, values) {
   return values;
}
coll.mapReduce(function() { map(this) }, reduce, function(err, results) {
   results.sort((a,b) => { return a._id > b._id });
   results.forEach(result => {
      console.log("now getting ids with " + result._id + " fields");
      var cursor = coll.find({ _id : { $in : result.value}});
      // do something with cursor.
   });
);
```

Another option would be to add a field to each doc "`fields_count`" which will hold the number of fields for that document, and you can use that field to query by.

Comment: I'm looking for a server side solution to this, preferably, where I don't have to sort the results. This would be last resort. but thanks anyways.

Comment: an obvious solution might be to add a field to each doc "fields_count", that you could use to sort by

Comment: That would be a good option, I think this should solves the problem. Also, @marmor Do you know a way to fetch collection metadata from mongoDB itself to get all the distinct columns that a collection has?? like Information Schema that MySQL has.

Comment: i'll update my answer to include the comment. regarding distinct columns, mongodb is schemaless, so it can't know which fields exists w/o going over all documents in the collection. you can do that using mapReduce as well, if you need help, search StackOverlow (or ask a new question)

Comment: I think Map-reduce is a way to go, and might be the best solution. I'll use your snippet. Thanks for the help.